# Is the GNU find -size flag broken?

Tags: find, gnu

The `-size` flag for GNU `find` behaves strangely.  Let's say I have the following three files in a directory:

```
$ lh
total 8.7M
-rw------- 1 wvoq wvoq  42K 2012-05-24 18:25 small
-rw------- 1 wvoq wvoq 7.3K 2012-05-24 18:37 tiny
-rw------- 1 wvoq wvoq 8.7M 2012-05-24 18:37 big
```

Two of the files are less than 1MB, and the other is about 9MB.  Which of the files are less than 50K in size?

```
$ find -type f -size -50k
small
tiny
```

Which is what we expect.  But which are less than 1MB in size?

```
$ find -type f -size -1M
$
```

Necessarily, any file less than 50k is also less than 1M, so why the discrepancy?  Even more disturbingly, we have:

```
$ find -type f -size -2M
small
tiny
```

which would seem to suggest that `small` and `tiny` are between 1 and 2 MB in size, when in fact they are both <50k.  What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like find is, ummm, violating the principle of least surprise? with its rounding behavior.  What's less than 1M? 0M.  :-P

Comment: Yep.  For anyone else who finds this page, see the thread on the findutils bug-tracker here: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=12162